# Ход компьютера в крестики-нолики

Tags: c#, wpf

Как реализовать ход компьютера (не в плане реализации логики хода компьютера), а именно логику вызова его хода? Т.е. после события моего хода, должно вызваться событие (или метод) хода компьютера, вот я не могу догнать как это сделать.

Выглядит всё примерно так. У меня имеется размеченный грид 3*3 (как игровое поле). когда я делаю клик по какому-то квадратику, то происходит событие нажатия кнопки мыши и у меня запускается метод проверки (пустая ли клеточка) и если она пустая, рисуется крестик или нолик.

Далее у меня меняется свойство - кто должен ходить и когда оно меняется срабатывает метод - ходит компьютер.

Проблема в том, что свойство меняется в обработчике событий и соответственно метод хода компьютера срабатывает внутри события тоже (т.е. событие ещё не отработало). И когда всё это отрабатывает, происходит отрисовка и крестика и нолика одновременно.
А я хочу сделать так, кликнул я в область, произошёл мой ход, нарисовался крестик. Затем например прошло 2 сек. (якобы компьютер подумал) и начал ходить компьютер, т.е. отрисовался нолик.

Comment: Просто сделать счётчик. На чётные ты, на нечётные ПК.

Comment: @sapeg Ну вот я походил (я кликнул в нужную область, вызвалось событие клика и всё мне отрисовало), теперь нужно как-то вызвать ход компьютера. Вот как это делать? Я не спрашиваю в какой момент мне вызывать ход компьютера, я спрашиваю как мне это делать?

Comment: Написать код хода компьютера и вызвать его в нужный момент.

Comment: Просто после хода игрока вызывайте метод хода ИИ: https://github.com/AndrewNowosad/Max8.NET/blob/edf85a93f847e8570583251739af16f5ab6f3fdb/Max8.NET/ViewModels/mainVm.cs#L111

Comment: Банальный таймер `var timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2) }`, который будет обрабатывать ход `timer.Tick += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { timer.Stop(); AITurn(); SwapTurn(); }`.

Comment: Можно в отдельную функцию

Comment: В том же самом onTouchLIstener запускаете оба варианта только каждый по условию (который я описал выше).

Comment: По ссылке что я вам дал как раз реализовано такое. ИИ начинает рассчитывать ход и одновременно запускается задержка 0.5 с, потом просто через Task.WhenAll ждём пока завершатся обе операции. Довольно красиво работает все.

Comment: Обращу внимание на все советы. Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим, у вас имеется некий метод, рассчитывающий лучший ход и возвращающий ячейку, в которую нужно сыграть компьютеру:

```
public Cell CalculateBestMove(...)
{
    ...
}
```

Создайте из этого метода задачу:

```
var calcTask = Task.Run(() => CalculateBestMove(...));
```

Теперь нам нужно написать задачу ожидания, поскольку штатный `Task.Delay` возвращает непараметризированную задачу, его здесь использовать неудобно, поэтому я написал такой простой хелпер:

```
class TplHelpers
{
    public static Task<T> Delay<T>(T returnValue, int milliseconds)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(milliseconds) { AutoReset = false };
        timer.Elapsed += delegate { timer.Dispose(); tcs.SetResult(returnValue); };
        timer.Start();
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public static Task<T> Delay<T>(int milliseconds)
        => Delay(default(T), milliseconds);
}
```

Используем этот хелпер для создания задачи ожидания, возвращающей фиктивное значение (которое мы использовать не будем):

```
var delayTask = TplHelpers.Delay<Cell>(500);
```

Теперь просто надо дождаться завершения обеих задач (если расчет будет выполнен быстро, то мы всё равно прождем эти 500 мс, если расчет займет свыше 500 мс, то мы прождем до его завершения), и взять результат первой задачи:

```
var cell = (await Task.WhenAll(calcTask, delayTask))[0];
```

Всё!